# Did I parameterize this correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have that $|z - i| = 1$ which is the equation for a circle in the complex plane. I know the center is at (0,1) and the radius is 1 so I did $z(t) = x(t) + iy(t)$. $x(t)$ is just $cos(t)$ and y(t) would be $1 + sin(t)$ so $z(t) = cos(t) + i(1 + sin(t)) = i + e^\left(it\right)$. Can someone confirm I did this right/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right, and more generally, if you have $|z-z_0| = r$, then you can parametrize this (a circle with center $z_0$ and radius $r$) as $z(t) = z_0 + r e^{it}$.

Comment: Ok thanks, now i have to find $\int |z|^2(z\bar + i)dz$, I'm a little lost on how to start. All i know so far is that the limits are from 0 to $\2\pi$

Comment: Whoops, the bar should be just over the z, not the + sign